# How many Indexes can we have on a document in MongoDB with the help of Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document with more than `50 fields`. I have to filter the documents based on 6 fields.
Is it possible to `index` 6 fields on a document?

is there any performance issue if I **create indexes** for 6 fields in a document?
thanks in advance.

```
export const ProclamationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    caption: { type: String, required: true },
    seniorityLevel: { type: Number, enum: [SeniorityLevel.Experienced, SeniorityLevel.Expert], required: true },
    collaborationType: { type: Number, enum: [CollaborationType.Fulltime, CollaborationType.Parttime], required: true },
    minimumSallery: { type: Number, required: true },
    minimumEducation: { type: Number, enum: [EducationType.AssociateDegree, EducationType.Bachelor], required: true },
    locationType: { type: Number, enum: [LocationType.Hybrid, LocationType.Remote], required: true, default: LocationType.Remote },
    categoryId: { type: Number, required: true },
    categoryCaption: { type: String, required: true },
    companyPersianName: { type: String, required: true },
    companyEnglishName: { type: String, required: true },
    companyId: { type: Number, required: true },
    companyLogo: { type: String, required: false },
    summary: { type: String, required: true },
    uniqueId: { type: String, required: true },
    publishDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    status: { type: Number, enum: [ProclamationStatus.Active, ProclamationStatus.Closed], required: true },
    labels: { type: [String], required: false },
    isActive: { type: Number, enum: [ActivationStatus.Active, ActivationStatus.Deactive] },
    language: { type: Number, enum: [LanguageEnum.English, LanguageEnum.Persian], required: true },
    ...
}).index({ labels: 1, minimumSallery: 1, locationType: 1, categoryId: 1, seniorityLevel:1, minimumEducation:1 })
```

**NOTE:**

90% the fields that I want to index are enum;

Comment: Are you creating six different single-key indexes or one composite index?

Comment: As an aside, you may want to fix the typo in `minimumSallery` (that should probably be `Salary`?)

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 64 indices per collection.

Source: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Number-of-Indexes-per-Collection

There is performance impact on index updates, as well as higher spec for RAM. You need to profile. If indices don't fit into the working set, it might be better to do without.

As a side note, this thing:

```
.index({ labels: 1, minimumSallery: 1, locationType: 1, categoryId: 1, seniorityLevel:1, minimumEducation:1 })
```

is 1 index, not 6. It might work not as you expect. Please learn what compound indices are, and how to use them: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-compound/#compound-indexes

Limit for number of fields in a compound index is 32.  Source https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Number-of-Indexed-Fields-in-a-Compound-Index